# Jcrop preview shifted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcrop

I'm using Jcrop and while it works fine, the preview image looks like it's being fed the wrong coordinates. I'm suspecting my javascript function is to blame, but I've been struggling for a few hours already with no solution in sight. Any help? Here's a fiddle with my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/1vetnqu0/

HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    <a class="lol" href="#este">Upload image!</a>
</div>

<div id="este" class="mfp-hide popup zoom-anim-dialog">
    <h4>Upload image</h4>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
        <img id="blah" class="crop" src="#" alt="your image" />
        <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
        <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
        <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
        <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />
    </form>

    <div style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:hidden; margin-top: 20px;">
        <img id="preview" />
    </div>

</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.lol').magnificPopup({
            type: 'inline',

            fixedContentPos: false,
            fixedBgPos: true,

            overflowY: 'auto',

            closeBtnInside: true,
            preloader: false,

            midClick: true,
            removalDelay: 300,
            mainClass: 'my-mfp-slide-bottom'
        });
    });

    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $('.crop').Jcrop({

                    onSelect: updateCoords,
                    onChange: showPreview,
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    bgOpacity:   .4,
                    setSelect:   [ 100, 100, 50, 50 ]

                });
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        console.log(this);
        readURL(this);
    });

    function updateCoords(c)
    {
        console.log(c);
        $('#x').val(c.x);
        $('#y').val(c.y);
        $('#w').val(c.w);
        $('#h').val(c.h);
    };

    function showPreview(coords)
    {
        var rx = 100 / coords.w;
        var ry = 100 / coords.h;

        $('#preview').css({
            width: Math.round(rx * 500) + 'px',
            height: Math.round(ry * 500) + 'px',
            marginLeft: '-' + Math.round(rx * coords.x) + 'px',
            marginTop: '-' + Math.round(ry * coords.y) + 'px'
        });
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I figured that the position is shifted because I need to change the 500px values on showPreview to the actual dimensions on the loaded image. How can I get those values from the file reader?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues with jCrop before. There are couple of props that might fix your issue here: trueSize and boxWidth, boxHeight

Ref page: http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Sizing_Issues.html